# How is a $k$-form integrated over an oriented smooth $n$-manifold in the case it is connected?

Tags: integration, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, connectedness, orientation

I have seen in several answers to questions on this page stating that there is no way to integrate a $k$-form over an oriented smooth $n$-manifold if $k \neq n$. However I cite Tu in his book on manifolds (page 272):

> (Problem 23.3*) Suppose $N$ and $M$ are connected, oriented $n$-manifolds and
>   $F : N \to M$ is a diffeomorphism. Prove that for any $\omega \in
>  \Omega^k_c(M)$, $$ \int_N F^* \omega = \pm \int_M \omega $$  where the
>   sign depends on whether $F$ is orientation-preserving or
>   orientation-reversing.

That means it seems there is a way to make this definition in the case that $M,N$ is connected. But, does Tu mean that $n = k$? If not, is there some canonical way to make the definition such that can understand what he is asking to prove?

Comment: As the very beginning of section 23.4, they say that on a manifold of dimension $n$, you can only integrate $n$ forms with compact support, so maybe it's a typo?